# how to uninstall sticky gitbook old version

Tags: uninstallation, gitbook

I just installed gitboot on my ubuntu 14.04. Soon I found it erratic. gitbook -h shows the following:

```
home: gitbook -h

Usage: gitbook [options] [command]


Commands:

ls                        List versions installed locally
current                   Display currently activated version
ls-remote                 List remote versions available for install
fetch [version]           Download and install a <version>
alias [folder] [version]  Set an alias named <version> pointing to <folder>
uninstall [version]       Uninstall a version
update [tag]              Update to the latest version of GitBook
help                      List commands for GitBook
*                         run a command with a specific gitbook version

Options:

-h, --help               output usage information
-V, --version            output the version number
-v, --gitbook [version]  specify GitBook version to use
-d, --debug              enable verbose error
```

essential commands like 'build', 'serve','pdf', are even not in the help info! Nevertheless, I can use 'gitbook pdf' or 'gitbook serve'. So I checked its version, and found it is a very old 2.1.3. SO I used 'gitbook update' to get 2.6.7; and also installed the most updated version as well. Now I have:

```
home: gitbook ls
GitBook Versions Installed:

* 3.0.0-pre.9
  2.6.7

Run "gitbook update" to update to the latest version.
home: gitbook -V
      2.1.3
home:
```

I would like to get rid of the old version 2.1.3, but failed.

```
home: gitbook uninstall 2.1.3

Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/chensy/.gitbook/versions/2.1.3'
```

Any idea how to remove 2.1.3? Why 'gitbook -h' gave me an incomplete list of commands?

Answer (score 0):

The -V gives the version of the CLI, not the main gitbook module (which is 2.6.7 or 3.0.0).
You have the latest versions from each.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have `2.1.3`. That is `ENOENT` tells.

For any installed version, you can also uninstall it by just deleting its install directory. e.g.

```
rm -fr ~/.gitbook/versions/2.6.7
```